# nx versio 17.1.3 shows no exported member 'ModuleFederationConfig'

Tags: reactjs, webpack-module-federation

I have issue with NX version 17.1.3
After update from version 16, I am getting error `node_modules/@nx/devkit/index"' has no exported member 'ModuleFederationConfig'.ts(2694)`
this is strange and it is only showing in two files that are responsible for store app
my `module-fedration.config.js`

```
/**
 * @type {import('@nx/devkit').ModuleFederationConfig}
 **/
const moduleFederationConfig = {
  name: 'store-app',
  exposes: {
    './useStore': './src/store/useStore.ts',
  },
};

module.exports = moduleFederationConfig;
```

my `webpcak.config.js`

```
const { withModuleFederation } = require('@nx/react/module-federation');
const baseConfig = require('./module-federation.config');

/**
 * @type {import('@nx/devkit').ModuleFederationConfig}
 **/
const defaultConfig = {
  ...baseConfig,
};

module.exports = withModuleFederation(defaultConfig);
```

I have such type

```
/**
 * @type {import('@nx/devkit').ModuleFederationConfig}
 **/
```

in two other files and all is working fine :/